# Вызов методов родителей при множественном наследовании в Python

Tags: python, наследование, множественное-наследование

Копипаст из idle

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")
    def stop(self):
        print("stop A stop!")
    def pause(self):
        raise Exception("Not Implemented")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).stop()
        print("go B go!")


class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")
    def stop(self):
        super(C, self).stop()
        print("stop C stop!")


class E(B,C): pass

e=E()
```

e.go() вывел

```
stop A stop!
stop C stop!
go B go!
```

Непонятно откуда такой вывод

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала немного теории:

Когда вы дёргаете метод у объекта, интерпретатор пытается найти этот метод сначала у самого объекта, если не находит - то ищет у класса объекта, если и там не находит, то по очереди обходит всех предков класса, пока не найдёт.

Порядок обхода предков при множественном наследовании определяется алгоритмом `MRO C3`.

Хорошая статья об этом есть на Хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/62203/

Для вашего класса E в соответствии с `MRO C3` порядок обхода родителей будет таким:

```
E -> B -> C -> A -> object
```

В этом легко убедиться так:

```
print(E.__mro__)
```

Теперь по пунктам, что происходит в вашем коде:

1. Вы дёргаете для объекта `e` метод `go`
2. Интерпретатор ищёт `go` в `e`. Не находит.
3. Ищет `go` в классе `E`. Не находит.
4. Ищет `go` в классе `B`. Находит, начинает исполнять.
5. Ему нужно выполнить `super(B, self).stop()` Так как в данном случае `self` - это `e` (то есть объект класса `E`), то он будет делать обход в соответствии с порядком `B -> C -> A`. И, следовательно, будет искать stop не среди предков класса `B`, а в следующем по цепочке классе `C`.
6. В `C` метод `stop` есть, но в нём делается сначала `super(C, self).stop()` поэтому интерпретатор пойдёт в `A.stop`
7. В `A.stop` он напечатает `"stop A stop!"`, после чего вернётся в `C.stop`
8. В `C.stop` он напечатает `"stop C stop!"`, после чего вернётся в `B.go`
9. В `B.go` он напечатает `"go B go!"`

Вот и всё :)

Comment: @SourSourse, верно, что-то я тупанул, сейчас поправлю ответ. Но в целом этот момент всё равно на логику происходящего не влияет.